# Failed deploy application, can't find context63545228987704752.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I'm trying to run my java web application with netbeans 8.2 and apache tomcat 8.0.27.0, but when I hit the run button, it is not deploying and showing error.

Here is the error

```
ant -f "D:\\AA\\kerjaan\\erajaya project\\evshop-devl\\evshop-devl" -            
Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true - 
DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true "- 
Dbrowser.context=D:\\AA\\kerjaan\\erajaya project\\evshop-devl\\evshop-devl"    
run
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
Tomcat server started.
In-place deployment at D:\AA\kerjaan\erajaya project\evshop-devl\evshop- 
devl\build\web
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FMuhammad%2520Rizky%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext63545228987704752.xml&path=/evshop-devl
FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /evshop-devl
D:\AA\kerjaan\erajaya project\evshop-devl\evshop-devl\nbproject\build- 
impl.xml:1076: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 18 seconds)
```

when i check it to tomcat tab it said

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Muhammad Rizky\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\Muhammad Rizky\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
30-May-2018 10:52:30.323 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.27
30-May-2018 10:52:30.336 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 28 2015 08:17:25 UTC
30-May-2018 10:52:30.337 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.27.0
30-May-2018 10:52:30.337 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
30-May-2018 10:52:30.337 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
30-May-2018 10:52:30.337 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
30-May-2018 10:52:30.337 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre
30-May-2018 10:52:30.338 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_131-b11
30-May-2018 10:52:30.338 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
30-May-2018 10:52:30.338 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Muhammad Rizky\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base
30-May-2018 10:52:30.338 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27
30-May-2018 10:52:30.339 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|Lenovo-PC
30-May-2018 10:52:30.339 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Muhammad Rizky\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\logging.properties
30-May-2018 10:52:30.340 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
30-May-2018 10:52:30.340 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\endorsed
30-May-2018 10:52:30.340 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Muhammad Rizky\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base
30-May-2018 10:52:30.340 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27
30-May-2018 10:52:30.341 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Muhammad Rizky\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\temp
30-May-2018 10:52:30.341 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;D:\AA\kerjaan\oracleClient;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;D:\app\MuhammadRizky\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\FusionEngine;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Muhammad Rizky\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Muhammad Rizky\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sophos\Sophos SSL VPN Client\bin;.
30-May-2018 10:52:31.988 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
30-May-2018 10:52:33.944 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
30-May-2018 10:52:33.957 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
30-May-2018 10:52:33.966 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
30-May-2018 10:52:33.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 4809 ms
30-May-2018 10:52:34.167 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
30-May-2018 10:52:34.167 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.27
30-May-2018 10:52:34.223 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Muhammad Rizky\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml
30-May-2018 10:52:36.821 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
30-May-2018 10:52:37.101 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\Muhammad Rizky\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml has finished in 2,878 ms
30-May-2018 10:52:37.102 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Muhammad Rizky\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
30-May-2018 10:52:37.711 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
30-May-2018 10:52:37.741 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\Muhammad Rizky\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml has finished in 639 ms
30-May-2018 10:52:37.806 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
30-May-2018 10:52:37.863 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
30-May-2018 10:52:37.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 3903 ms
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Muhammad%20Rizky\AppData\Local\Temp\context63545228987704752.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.copyInternal(ManagerServlet.java:1634)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.copy(ManagerServlet.java:1598)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:344)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

but when i check  C:\Users\Muhammad%20Rizky\AppData\Local\Temp\context63545228987704752.xml
the xml file is exist

I already reinstalled my netbeans, 
changed my user name (because my user name contained space, I changed space with underscore),
run my netbeans as administrator

and still not working

do you guys know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

as i said, my user name has space on it, and after i change my user name the folder that represent my username doesn't change.

for now i just make a new user for me, use a user name that doesn't contain space on it and it work.

but ofcourse it doesn't fix the main problem but at least it work